# Explain the use of yields in this Game of Life implementation

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools, yield, conways-game-of-life

In [this PyCon talk](http://pyvideo.org/video/880/stop-writing-classes), Jack Diederich shows this "simple" implementation of [Conway's Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life#Rules). I am not intimately familiar with either GoL or semi-advanced Python, but the code seems quite easy to grasp, if not for two things:

1. The use of `yield`. I have seen the use of yield to create generators before, but eight of them in a row is new... Does it return a list of eight generators, or how does this thing work?
2. `set(itertools.chain(*map(neighbors, board)))`. The star unpacks the resulting list (?) from applying neighbours to board, and ... my mind just blew.

Could someone try to explain these two parts for a programmer that is used to hacking together some python code using map, filter and reduce, but that is not using Python on a daily basis? :-)

```
import itertools

def neighbors(point):
    x, y = point
    yield x + 1, y
    yield x - 1, y
    yield x, y + 1
    yield x, y - 1
    yield x + 1, y + 1
    yield x + 1, y - 1
    yield x - 1, y + 1
    yield x - 1, y - 1

def advance(board):
    newstate = set()
    recalc = board | set(itertools.chain(*map(neighbors, board)))
    for point in recalc:
        count = sum((neigh in board) for neigh in neighbors(point))
        if count == 3 or (count == 2 and point in board):
            newstate.add(point)
    return newstate

glider = set([(0,0), (1,0), (2, 0), (0,1), (1,2)])
for i in range(1000):
    glider = advance(glider)
    print glider
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generators operate on two principles: they produce a value each time a `yield` statement is encountered, and unless it is iterated over, their code is *paused*.

It doesn't matter how many `yield` statements are used in a generator, the code is still run in normal python ordering. In this case, there is no loop, just a series of `yield` statements, so each time the generator is advanced, python executes the next line, which is another `yield` statement.

What happens with the `neighbors` generator is this:

1. Generators always start paused, so calling `neighbors(position)` returns a generator that hasn't done anything yet.
2. When it is advanced (`next()` is called on it), the code is run until the first `yield` statement. First `x, y = point` is executed, then `x + 1, y` is calculated and yielded. The code pauses again.
3. When advanced again, the code runs until the *next* `yield` statement is encountered. It yields `x - 1, y`.
4. etc. until the function completes.

The `set(itertools.chain(*map(neighbors, board)))` line does:

1. `map(neighbors, board)` produces an iterator for each and every position in the `board` sequence. It simply loops over board, calls `neighbors` on each value, and returns a new sequence of the results. Each `neighbors()` function returns a generator.
2. The `*parameter` syntax expands the `parameter` sequence into a list of parameters, as if the function was called with each element in `parameter` as a separate positional parameter instead. `param = [1, 2, 3]; foo(*param)` would translate to `foo(1, 2, 3)`.

   `itertools.chain(*map(..))` takes each and every generator produced by the map, and applies that as a series of positional parameters to `itertools.chain()`. Looping over the output of chain means that each and every generator for each and every board position is iterated over once, in order.
3. All the generated positions are added to a set, essentially removing duplicates

You could expand the code to:

```
positions = set()
for board_position in board:
    for neighbor in neighbors(board):
        positions.add(neighbor)
```

In python 3, that line could be expressed a little more efficiently still by using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) instead, because `map()` in Python 3 is a generator too; `.from_iterable()` doesn't force the `map()` to be expanded and will instead loop over the `map()` results one by one as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that's a neat implementation, thanks for posting it !

For the `yield`, there is nothing to add to Martijn's answer.

As for the star : the `map` returns a generator or a list (depending on python 2 or 3), and each item of this list is a generator (from `neighbors`), so we have a list of generators.

[`chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) takes many arguments that are iterables and chains them, meaning it returns a single iterable while iterate over all of them in turn.

Because we have a list of generators, and `chain` takes many arguments, we use a star to convert the list of generator to arguments. We could have done the same with [`chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

Answer (score 0):

it just returns a tuple of all cell's neighbours. If you do understand what generators do, it is pretty clear that using generators is a good practice when working with big amount of data. you do not need to store all this in memory, you calculate it only when you need it.